# How to use packagesbuild with GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

[One of my Open Source projects](https://github.com/JanosGit/Schrammel_OJD) uses [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) to build the macOS installer. After GUI-based setup of the pckgproject file, the installer build can be easially invoked from the command line through the `packagesbuild` command.

I'm now setting up a GitHub Actions based build workflow, running on the GitHub-hosted runners, which should ideally create a ready-to-use installer, so I need to invoke packagesbuild during that process. Unfortunately `packagesbuild` is not available on the `macos-10.15` runner used. I don't see any option to install it during the workflow run, as it's not available through e.g. homebrew but maybe I'm overlooking something. Is there any option I'm overlooking beneath rebuilding my installer and switching to pkgbuild?

Comment: Download it in your workflow and install it / copy it (see also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73926/is-there-a-command-to-install-a-dmg)